Creating a restriction (GPO or EntraID,etc) or notification if onedrive path is too long
Is it possible to create a somekind of a restriction in M365,AzureAD or Microsoft graph for length of a file or folder or at least a notification if filepath in Onedrive is too long and because of that cant be sync.
